# Why is an empty array being logged in ReactJS when fetching data from MongoDB using context API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I am fetching data from MongoDB in my ReactJS app using context API. When I log the data to the web page, I get three arrays instead of one. I am unsure why this is happening.

Here is my code:

In RoomProvider.js file:

I have created a context using React.createContext.
In the constructor of RoomProvider, I have initialized state with users, rooms, sortedRooms, featuredRooms, and loading.
I am using axios to fetch data from MongoDB in two separate methods - getRooms() and getUsers().
I have a getRoom() method that returns a specific room.
In componentDidMount(), I call getRooms() and set loading to false.
In the render() method, I am providing the state and getRoom() method to the context provider.
In RoomContainer.js file:

I am consuming the context using the withRoomConsumer() higher-order component.
I am logging the rooms array to the console.
When I run the app, the console shows me an empty array being logged three times, instead of one array. I am unsure why this is happening.

Can someone please help me understand why I am seeing an empty array being logged three times? Here is my code:

(Include the code for RoomProvider.js, RoomContainer.js, and any other relevant files.)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like its working as expected, you see 3 logs because the component got rendered 3 times.

1. First render - There is no data because the fetch (in
   `componentDidMount`) wasn't triggered yet.
2. Second render - State was updated (with `loading: false`) and fetch
   was triggered, but the call wasn't fulfilled yet, so still no data.
3. Third render - The data returned and state was updated, now you have
   the data.

Comment: Thank you very mush Sagiv! What is the best way to make the changes I need?

Comment: Why do you need to change it? This is a normal behaviour and flow.

Comment: Because I want to use the rooms array and display it on the web page. Instead of it I get empty array and I cant display nothing!

Comment: But eventually the array is not empty. Asynchronous data fetching is slower than rendering and there's nothing we can do about it. We can handle this by [conditionally render](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) the data, maybe showing a loader until we have our data ready for display.

Comment: @רועיאנגל  if you think you got an answer to your question feel free to accept and mark your question as answered